# How to vectorize for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, memory, vectorization

I am new to C++ , so I was wondering whether for loops can be vectored in C++. In Python,Matlab , vectorization adds performance, SIMD operations , I was wondering whether this was possible in C++ ? If so how ? If it is long could you point me to a tutorial ?

```
template <class T>
matrix<T> matrix<T>::operator*( matrix<T> &rhs)
/*
    it takes the current matrix , multiplies it by the matrix on the right , and returns 
    a new matrix 
*/
{
    matrix<T> result(_rows,rhs._cols);

    if(_cols == rhs._rows ){
                for(long long  i = 1; i <= _rows ;i++){
                    for(long long  j = 1 ; j <= rhs._cols ; j++){
                        for(long long  k = 1; k <= _cols ; k++)
                            result(i,j) += get(i,k) * rhs(k,j);// get(i,k) gives the elements in the current matrix. 

                    }   
                }
        //}else error("Cols Does Not Match");
    }else error("Rows Does Not Match");

    return result ; 
}
```

I am doing more complicated loops in my class matrix , if you could give me a heuristic on how to do vectorization , it would help tremendously.

Side Note- (Should I make this a separate question ?) 
I am implementing the matrix as a 1D std::vector. For sizes of 30000 X 30000 (10^8) , I get a debug error in VS. I searched online and found the limit of std::vector to be ~ 50 million . How can I support matrices of larger size. Matlab support about 2 billion (10^9) vector element or more. What can I do in C++ to get the same size ? Should I fall back to using arrays and do the memory allocation myself?

Thank you.

Comment: Is that 10^8 matrix a sparse matrix or a regular one? If it's a non-sparse matrix you have to find better ways to manage the memory and potentially  work on some improved memory management schemes if it doesn't completely fit into memory.

Comment: With respect to size, it very much depends on whether you're compiling for 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: @TimoGeusch Non Spare matrix. could you give me a book or a website to learn about doing it ? I am new to this. -thank you

Comment: `30000 X 30000` is **HUGE** (3.4 Gb at least if you use `int`s of 4 bytes). Consider the fact that you (usually) need 4 bytes for an `int` and probably 8 for a `double`.

Comment: @Robinson I have a 62 bit computer , I use VS , but I don't know whether the exe is 64 or 32 bit. I will search and come back.

Comment: @nnrales quick and dirty way of finding out: `cout << sizeof(char*)`

Comment: @vsoftco so what you are saying is that this can't be done ? I have 6 gb free ram , but what I am looking for is a Data Structure or technique in C++ which lets me allocate more memory

Comment: By storing it as vector of vectors, you can relax the contiguous layout constant and make it easier for the compiler. If you can afford such a change, it's worth trying.

Comment: @nnrales it depends on your operating system and not on C++ per se. AFAIK, Win32 doesn't allow you to allocate more than 2GB (although in theory you should be able to allocate 4GB). Win64 probably lets you. However, when working with such large matrices, think also about how long operations on them will take. The time scales exponentially bad with the size of the matrix.

Comment: @nnrales then your exe is addressing memory in 32 bit (4 bytes) mode, see my comment above.

Comment: @user3528438 I moved from 2 D to 1 D as I read 1 D prevented cache misses hence better performance. This is disappointing .Okay , if it lets me store more , I am willing to change.

Comment: 1D can not prevent cache miss, it just makes it more predictable, hence controllable. But in this case, that is really less priority.

Comment: Why not use a library like [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/)?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872235.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For 'Vectorization' of for-loops you could use OpenMP http://openmp.org/wp/ or Intel TBB.

If you do not want to implemented basic-mathematical functions yourself you can use Math-Libs like Armadillo http://arma.sourceforge.net/. They are doing the optimization for you.